# Minimized windows form to system tray

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Below is my failed code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {                                                                                      
            Hide();
        }
    }

    private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Show();
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }

}
```

When I click minimized, it is still appear on my taskbar. Do you guys know what's wrong?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Avoid writing code that makes a class listen to its own events.  Events are meant to tell *other* code in other classes what is happening to the form.  Override OnResize() instead, you can never forget to subscribe the event that way.  Which is surely what you forgot to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ShowInTaskbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to remove form from taskbar:

```
private void MainForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)        
        ShowInTaskbar = false;        
}

private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ShowInTaskbar = true;
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 in Windows 7. Does that have anything to do with my problem?

Comment: I have tried to put a breakpoint in MainForm_Resize but it did not stop there. Seems like it did not went into MainForm_Resize event..

Comment: @Coolguy you don't need to `Hide` or `Show` form manually when you are minimizing it or restoring its state. Verified on .NET 4.5 with Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to: http://developerpr.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/c-handle-minimize-maximize-restore-in-windows-forms-before-it-happens/

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    var msg = '\x112';
    const int minimize = '\xf020';
    const int maximize = '\xf030';
    const int restore = '\xf120';

    if (m.Msg == msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.ToString());
        var param = m.WParam.ToInt32();
        switch (param)
        {
            case minimize:
                // handle minimize             
                ShowInTaskbar = false;
                break;
            case maximize:
                // handle maximize             
                break;
            case restore:
                // handle restore      
                ShowInTaskbar = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I changed the order of calling the base.WndProc and handling the message. Otherwise the minimize is cancelled on first click.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what's wrong. I'm missing an event handler declaration in my Form1.Designer.cs file.
I've added the below under Form1 and it works:

```
this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Resize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

this.ShowInTaskbar = false;

and in show()

this.ShowInTaskbar = true;